# Joining value A from table 1 to Value B and C from Table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Table `staff` contains a list of staff names, numbers and staffID's. Table `Entries` contains entries received from staff members to vote for other staff members. This table only shows Staff Member who voted, and the Staff member who was voted for's cellphone numbers.

I want to show which cell number belongs to which staff member by doing a join to the `staff` table.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/ 

SELECT
    'Garden Court East Gate'
    ,[entries].[PropertyId]
    ,entries.[RatingCellNum] as 'Voting Staff Member Cell Number'
    ,staff.firstname as 'Votee'
    ,staff.Lastname as 'Voted For'
    ,entries.[ToRateCellNum] as 'Rated for Cell Number'
    ,staff.firstname as 'Votee Name'
    ,staff.Lastname as 'Voted Surname'
    ,entries.[MomentRatedFor] as 'Moments Value'
    ,entries.[DateVoted] as 'Date'
    ,Entries.StaffNumber
FROM [UD_SuperHero].[dbo].[Entries](nolock)
INNER JOIN [UD_SuperHero].[dbo].[staff](nolock) ON Entries.ToRateCellNum = staff.CellphoneNumber
WHERE entries.PropertyId = '79'
ORDER BY DateVoted desc
```

This works to link the relevant staff member with matching cell number to the ToRateCellNum.

How do I get the matching staff member from the same `staff` table to match against the cell number value for RatingCellNum?

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired result in formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine if the tables were two different staff tables you would have no problem, and that is how you handle this.

You call the same table twice with two different aliases:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    Entries
    INNER JOIN Staff as Voters ON Entries.StaffNumber = Voters.StaffID
    INNER JOIN Staff as Votees ON Entries.ToRateCellNum = Votees.CellNum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Entries
JOIN Staff as Voters 
  ON Entries.StaffNumber   = Voters.StaffID
  OR Entries.ToRateCellNum = Voters.CellNum
```